# Emptied SQL Server Database broke the Cube

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have a SQL Server hosting our Analysis Services and accessing data from the ERP system by a ETL process. It was some duplicates in the data and therefore the SQL Server database was emptied. After running the ETL process again the end status is DTSER_SUCCESS. The data in the SQL Server database tables is refreshed and do get an updated Last_Loaded timestamp but nothing will display from the Cube now.

What is the reason for this and how can it be resolved?

This message is in the log file despite the DTSER_SUCCESS status:
The external columns for Error Destination are out of synchronization with the data source columns. The external column "OBJID" needs to be updated.